# What is foursquare place price options?

Tags: foursquare, price

I am integrating foursquare place api.
They provide place price as numeric value (1~4)
This is their official doc
[image]

I want to know exact price value.
For example, for **1 Cheap => 1$ ~ 100$**

They have no explain about this.
Where can I get this info?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The price value is a relative allocation. The algorithm scraped menu prices and does a comparison of nearby places (simplest way to explain it). So there isn't an actual dollar amount assigned to any tier.